# Vaadin - Hide UI when session expires

Tags: session, user-interface, vaadin

I'm doing a project in Vaadin 7. In that I need to hide my UI(or disable access to UI) when a user session expires.

I tried overriding the

```
@Override
public void close() {
// some stuff to disable UI
}
```

But, Nothing has happened. Is it possible to disable the components in my UI after session expires.

or any other ideas to hide my UI after session expires.

Comment: What do you mean by "session expires" ?
If you mean the normal http session, then it is too late, since at that moment the connection between browser and associated instance is lost, so you can't update it from server side.
I think you must decide how sessions are closed in your application. Letting the http session expire causes bad user experience, better keep the session open until the user closes them.

Comment: Why do you want to close the UI? What problems are you getting?

Comment: @enkara I manually close the user session when a user is logged in for the second time. I want the UI closed because the UI contains some confidential data.

Comment: @AndréSchild you are right. But, the vaadin guys say that the method close() will be called when a session expires https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/139230. So, I tried to override it to do my stuffs.

Comment: No, the moment the close() is happening, the connection to the browser is finished, so you can't disable the UI components.

But instead of closing the session, just remove all elemnts from the screen and show a simple "You have been logged out because...." message. No need to terminate the session.

Answer (score 0):

For Vaadin 7, you can implement a DetachListener and add it to the UI like so:

```
final DetachListener detachListener = new DetachListener() {
            @Override
            public void detach(final DetachEvent detachEvent) {
                //Cleanup resource before session is closed.
            }
        };
...

((YourUI) UI.getCurrent()).addDetachListener(detachListener);
```

Comment: Note: This also gets executed if you reload the page (e.g. `F5`)